# Kubernetes (delete Replica Sets)

Tags: java, kubernetes

How can I remove replicasets from kubernetes? 
I use kubernetes-client java libs, 
the request there looks like this:
`/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/{namespace}/replicasets/{name}`
but I do not know the name replicasets, I know only label selector.
Configure such a request does not allow me lib:
`/apis/extensions/v1beta1/namespaces/va/replicasets/labelSelector=app=some_name`

Comment: Couldn't you just get all replica sets with your label selector and discover the name?

Answer (score -1):

When you [create a replica-set](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/ExtensionsV1beta1Api.md#createNamespacedReplicaSet) your return type from that method is an object representing the replica-set. You should be able to get the name of the replica-set from that object and then, later on, use it in order to [delete it](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/ExtensionsV1beta1Api.md#deleteNamespacedReplicaSet).

Another option would be to [list all replica-sets](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/ExtensionsV1beta1Api.md#listReplicaSetForAllNamespaces), and add a label selector to this call. This will only return the replica-sets you're looking for and then you can delete those.